# Mock Native Module Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs

In my React-Native application i wanna write some unit tests for my Native Libraries.

**dataStorage.js**

```
import RNDataStorage, {ACCESSIBLE} from "react-native-data-storage";

const dataStorage = {
    setData: function (key, value) {
        return RNDataStorage.set(key, value, {accessible: ACCESSIBLE.ALWAYS_THIS_DEVICE_ONLY})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            return true;
        })
    },
}

export default dataStorage;
```

**dataStorage.test.js**

```
import dataStorage from '../../src/services/dataStorage'

jest.mock('react-native-data-storage', () => {
    return {
        RNDataStorage: {
            set: jest.fn(),
        }
    };
});

it('Should return Access & RefreshToken', function () {
    dataStorage.setData('John', 'Test');
});
```

When i run this setup i receive the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`.

What is the correct way to mocks some modules? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module you are mocking is an ES6 module with a default export and a named export.

Mocking it like this should get your test running:

```js
jest.mock('react-native-data-storage', () => {
    return {
      __esModule: true,
      default: {
        set: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('the response'))
      },
      ACCESSIBLE: {
        ALWAYS_THIS_DEVICE_ONLY: true
      }
    };
});
```

Answer based on [this post](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5579#issuecomment-397406174)